# Streams reading/writing causing deadlock?

Tags: c#, concurrency, stream, delegates, deadlock

I have the following code snippet, which is executed in parallel by several threads:

```
private delegate Stream MyDelegate(string url);

private IAsyncResult BeginRequest(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    return ((MyDelegate)QuerySync).BeginInvoke(url, callback, state);
}

private Stream EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    return ((MyDelegate)((AsyncResult)result).AsyncDelegate).EndInvoke(result);
}

private Stream QuerySync(string url)
{
    return (this.client).GetHttpWebResponse(url).GetResponseStream();
}

public async Task<Stream> GetResponseStream(string url){    
    using (Stream input = await Task<Stream>.Factory.FromAsync(BeginRequest, EndRequest, url, null).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        await input.CopyToAsync(output).ConfigureAwait(false);
        output.Position = 0;
        return output;
    }
}
```

And, for some reason, the application sporadically stops inside my GetResponseStream() method (no exception is thrown, it justs hangs forever). I've looked around for possible causes and found out that apparently a deadlock might happen when trying to read and write from the same Stream in parallel. The problem is, I'm not actually reading and writing from the **same** Stream in that case (at least I think so). Because since I await for the recently created task that writes to the input stream to end before calling CopyToAsync (which obviously performs Reads to this Stream internally), the read only starts after the write has ended. So I don't see why this could cause a deadlock since I never read and write from the same Stream at the same time.

I don't know if that matters, but as a side note, my QuerySync method is completely synchronous, as the client I'm using to get responses currently does not support asynchronous requests.

Comment: Getting the stream from the response from the client at the same time from multiple threads certainly sounds like a bad idea.  It wouldn't expect that client to be designed to have multiple threads reading its response stream at the same time, and that's what you're doing.  Create multiple clients if you want to be performing multiple operations in parallel, or have one thread read the data and expose it to multiple threads after putting it into a data structure.

Comment: @Servy: I tried to simplify the code but I guess I omitted an important requirement (edited to clarify that) -- each call to GetResponseStream gives an URL that is passed to the client, so each call actually corresponds to a different response, and therefore I would not be able to read the data once and then expose it. Also, creating multiple clients would ruin the application's performance as it would add too much overheads.

Comment: Well, choose one, a "high performance" application that doesn't work and deadlocks because it's not thread safe, or a "poor performance" application that actually works correctly.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what is the cause for the deadlock.

Comment: You're using a class that isn't designed to be used from multiple threads from multiple threads.  Most anything can happen when you do that, from deadlocks, exceptions, wrong results, the world blowing up, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The client that you are using to perform these requests is not designed to be accessed from multiple threads in parallel.  You'll need to create multiple clients so that they are never accessed from separate threads.